# Determine whether a function possess the intermediate value property

Tags: calculus

Most of the books or online lecture notes that i have looked up always conclude whether a function possess the I.V.P without further explanation . But how do we know that? Take sin(1\x) for an example. Professors always tell us that this is a classic example for those who posses I.V.P but don't satisfies I.V.T. So,how do we examine that this is true?

Comment: A continuous function satisfies the intermediate value property. What do you mean by $\sin(1/x)$ not satisfying the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What's the domain in question of your function $\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: @PedroM. I think the OP is referring to [Darboux functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function), e.g. with $x\in[0,\infty)\mapsto \begin{cases}\sin\frac{1}{x} & x > 0\\ 0&x=0\end{cases}$ which is not continuous on its domain.

Comment: Yes,that is what i am referring to. Sorry for making you confused.

Answer (score 0):

The Intermediate Value Theorem states the following:

Let $f$ by a continuous function in $[a,b]$ and let $xi$ be some number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=\xi$.

The example $f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin(1/x) \quad x>0 \\ 0 \quad \quad \quad x=0\end{cases}$

is not continuous in any interval $[0,\alpha],\alpha>0$ since $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Therefore we cannot apply the IVT to derive any information about $f$ in $[0,\alpha],\alpha>0$.

However, it DOES verify an IVP. Let $\xi$ be between $f(0)=0$ and $f(\alpha), \alpha>0$.  There exists $N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that ${1\over N\pi}<\alpha$. Now $\xi$ is between $f({1\over N\pi})=0$ and $f(\alpha)$. Since $f$ is continuous in $[{1\over N\pi},\alpha]$ there exist $c \in [{1\over N\pi},\alpha]$ such that $f(c)=\xi$. In particular, $c \in [0,\alpha]$, as desired.

Comment: So, why does f(1/N)=0?

Comment: It doesn't. $f\left ({1 \over N\pi} \right )$ does, because: $f\left ({1 \over N\pi} \right )=\sin \left( {1 \over 1/(N\pi)} \right )=\sin(N\pi)=0$